# Is my pineapple plant going to grow a pineapple?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, indoors, growth, pineapple

I have had this pineapple plant for a year now and it seems like nothing has really changed from when I first got it. There are a lot more leaves, and there's a really nice thick stem, but there is no pineapple growing from it. I can add an image later on in the forum. I just really am confused what I should do with this plant now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More sunshine will have to help.

Comment: On an older book I read about need to wait 7 years. I'm not sure about such interval, but my experience tell me it requires many years (or better climate).

Answer (score 2):

I have 5 pineapple plants that I grew from the crowns of fruit bought at the grocery store.  It took about two years for a pineapple plant to mature enough to produce fruit and about two years for the pineapple fruit to grow. So for me it was about 4 years before I was able to reap the rewards.  Also, I've heard if the climate where you live is not tropical enough, the plant will not produce fruit and will only be ornamental.  I live in San Diego, CA and am probably about as close to the edge as you can get of the tropical climate before the plants stop producing, if that is true.  I leave the plants outside all year, and they are individually planted in their own pots which are about 20 gallon pots.